# C++ pointer to a class, not object

Tags: c++, class, pointers

I want my map generator to fill some part of map with given tile, but I dont know how to pass that value, I need to make NEW object with given TYPE (which is one of parameters)... For example:

```
void flood(/*???*/ pattern, double radius_val, tile *map[20][20], int x, int y)
{
     if (radius_val<0) return;
     map[x][y]=new pattern();
     flood(pattern,radius_val-1, map, x+1, y);
     //... more code
};
```

I dont know how to show flooder what type of object is he going to make... Pattern should be pointing on one of the tile class children (for example tile_tree).

Thanx for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Function arguments cannot be types, because function arguments hold values and types are not values. Template arguments, however, can be types.

```
template <typename pattern>
void flood(double radius_val, tile *map[20][20], int x, int y)
{
     if (radius_val<0) return;
     map[x][y]=new pattern();
     flood<pattern>(radius_val-1, map, x+1, y);
     //... more code
};
```

Basically, this creates a new function for each `pattern` you want to use, but without the hassle of typing out all the function definitions.

Comment: so in my case (I want tile_tree) how to use this function? flood<tile_tree>(/*args*/)?